# Yii CHtml::ajaxSubmitButton always submits data in POST method

Tags: php, ajax, yii, yii-chtml

I came across this problem when I used CHtml::ajaxSubmitButton to submit some of the data as a GET method. No Matter what i try, It always submits data as a POST method.

Anything that I might be doing wrong? Here's my code.

```
echo CHtml::beginForm(array('shoppingCart/addItem','GET')); 
echo CHtml::textField('qty', 1, array('size' => 3));
echo CHtml::hiddenField('product_id', $model->product_id); echo CHtml::ajaxSubmitButton('submit',          
                array('shoppingCart/addItem'), 
                array(
                        'type'=>'GET',
                        //'data' => array()),
                ));

echo CHtml::endForm();
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That is by design. You can use `CHtml::ajaxButton` instead:

```
CHtml::ajaxButton('My Label','controller/action',array(
            'type'=>'GET',
        ), array(
            'type'=>'submit',
        );
```

Comment: This is the way to go about it :) Thank you very much

Answer (score 3):

Regarding to [this document](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/1.1/CHtml#ajaxSubmitButton-detail) the value of `type` will be overwritten.

```
public static function ajaxSubmitButton($label,$url,$ajaxOptions=array(),$htmlOptions=array())
{
    $ajaxOptions['type']='POST';
    $htmlOptions['type']='submit';
    return self::ajaxButton($label,$url,$ajaxOptions,$htmlOptions);
}
```

So there is no way to use GET as long as you do not touch the core function.

Comment: It doesn't make any difference.

Comment: Well, [this document](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/1.1/CHtml#ajaxSubmitButton-detail) just says, that ajax sends with POST. Maybe GET is only possible when you use a non-ajax solution.

Comment: [Here](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/1.1/CHtml#ajaxSubmitButton-detail) you can see this line `$ajaxOptions['type']='POST';` makes it impossible to use `GET` for the ajaxSubmitButton. I'll update my answer.